# How can a rung a command from an err-bot plugin from another err-bot plugin?

Tags: errbot

How can a rung a command from an err-bot plugin from another err-bot plugin?

run the "!dosomething" from another plugin on some type of scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try asking questions about errbot at gitter: https://gitter.im/errbotio/errbot

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command from another plugin by calling the method directly. self.get_plugin(PluginName) after your plugin is activated will get you an instance of the other plugin. You can then call methods from that plugin.

```
from errbot import BotPlugin, botcmd


class MyPlugin(BotPlugin):

    def activate(self):
            super().activate()  # <-- needs to be *before* get_plugin
            self.get_plugin('Duo2fa').add_command('foo_bar')

            @botcmd
            def foo_bar(self, msg, args):
                    return "Bar" # will only run if --2fa is passed
```

This example is from https://github.com/andrewthetechie/errbot-duo2fa

> on some type of scheduler.

Errbot offers pollers that let you run code on a schedule. Documentation is here: https://errbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/scheduling.html

You can also use another scheduling library and run it in a separate thread as part of your plugin. Here's an example in another plugin https://github.com/andrewthetechie/err-topic-a-day/blob/main/topic-a-day.py using apscheduler.